# What exactly does GenerateConditions do?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

Consider for example this strange behavior:

```
Integrate[1/x, {x, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]
(*0*)
```

I'd also like to know the difference between `GenerateConditions -> Automatic` and `GenerateConditions -> True`.

Comment: Seems to be a bug; I suspect an examination of the mess produced by `TracePrint[Integrate[1/x, {x, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False], TraceInternal -> True]` might give a few clues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a quick description.

`GenerateConditions -> False` will both skip some code for checking parameter regions of validity for an integral, and also a regularized integral might be computed. This interface should probably be improved but I've no idea if or when that might happen.

`GenerateConditions -> Automatic` behaves like `True` for single definite integrals. In the multiple case it behaves like `False` for all inner integrals, and `True` for the final integration step. The reason is that the ability to spawn conditions is more powerful than the code required to sort through them, so defaulting to `True` at all levels might keep many inputs from running to completion.

There are probably exceptions to this general categorization.