# Integrate and ConditionalExpression Output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am integrating some difficult functions and using the conditional output to place bounds on parameters to ensure integrability, but it seems that not all of the conditions are being returned. The following simple example illustrates the issue.

When I perform the 1D integration

```
Integrate[Exp[b y], {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

I receive the correct output

```
ConditionalExpression[-(1/b), Re[b] < 0]
```

but when I perform the 2D integration

```
Integrate[Exp[a x + b y], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

I only receive

```
ConditionalExpression[1/(a b), Re[a] < 0].
```

That is, the condition on the parameter `b` ensuring integrability is not returned. In this case does Mathematica only return the condition associated with the last integration step?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to set `GenerateConditions` explicitly

```
Integrate[Exp[a x + b y], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]

(* ConditionalExpression[1/(a b), Re[b] < 0 && Re[a] < 0] *)
```

Comment: For more info, see Daniel Lichtblau's answers: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13458, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46492