# A discrepancy between the analytical and numerical integration results

Tags: numerical-integration

Let us integrate the expression:

```
I*y*(1/(x - I*y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I*y)^(5/2))
```

over a rectangle in the `(x,y)` plane, where x varies from -10 to 10, while y varies from 0 to 10. This integral can be solved analytically:

```
I*Integrate[
  y*(1/(x - I*y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I*y)^(5/2)), {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
% // N

(* -(8/3) Sqrt[5] (2 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[-1 + 5 Sqrt[2]] - \[Pi] - ArcCosh[3]) *)

(*  -2.31 *)
```

The last line here is the numeric value of the integral that I will use for comparisons below.

Now let us try to solve it numerically with several methods

```
 Quiet[Chop[
    I*NIntegrate[
      y *(1/(x - I y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I y)^(5/2)), {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0,
        10}, Method -> #]]] & /@ {"LocalAdaptive", \
{"EvenOddSubdivision", Method -> "LocalAdaptive"}, 
  "AdaptiveMonteCarlo", "QuasiMonteCarlo", 
  "MonteCarlo", {"EvenOddSubdivision", 
   Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"}, {"EvenOddSubdivision", 
   Method -> "DuffyCoordinates"}}
```

(*  {2.16, 2.16, 2.12, 2.26, 1.59, 2.33, 2.18}  *)

Some of these methods do not, but some give warnings. I quieted them just to focus on the essential.

What strikes the eye here is that while the result of the exact solution is negative, the numerical result is positive.

Why? Any ideas?

**Edit: **

One can go to the cylindrical coordinates:

```
expr = Simplify[
  TrigToExp[
   I*y*(1/(x - I*y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I*y)^(5/2)) /. {x -> 
      r*Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], y -> r*Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]}], {r > 0, 
   0 < \[CurlyPhi] < \[Pi]}]

(* (E^(-((7 I \[CurlyPhi])/
  2)) (-1 + E^(2 I \[CurlyPhi])) (-1 + E^(5 I \[CurlyPhi])))/(2 r^(
 3/2))  *)
```

and then integrate. In this case let us integrate it over the upper half-disk with the radius R=10:

```
Integrate[expr2*r, {r, 0, 10}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, \[Pi]}] // N

(*   2.41   *)
```

and numerically

```
Quiet[NIntegrate[expr2*r, {r, 0, 10}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, \[Pi]}, 
    Method -> #]] & /@ {"LocalAdaptive", {"EvenOddSubdivision", 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive"}, "AdaptiveMonteCarlo", 
  "QuasiMonteCarlo", 
  "MonteCarlo", {"EvenOddSubdivision", 
   Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"}, {"EvenOddSubdivision", 
   Method -> "DuffyCoordinates"}}



 (*    {2.41, 2.41, 2.43, 2.42, 2.28, 2.38, 2.41}   *)
```

In this case they have the same sign.

Comment: Maybe a different branch on the Sqrt (i.e., the ^5/2)?

Comment: @ bill s Have you an idea of how to fix the branch?

Comment: Maple is giving me `2.173299654`

Comment: Even stranger: you can check that the integrand is equal to $f(x,y)$ with `f[x_, y_] = y/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/2)*((x + I*y)^(5/2) - (x - I*y)^(5/2))`. However,   `I*Integrate[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]` returns  `-(8/3) Sqrt[-5 + 25 Sqrt[2]]` that is approx. `-14.69`. Since there is a singularity in $(0,0)$ I guess it might be related to the chosen branches. (That's probably not a problem here but note that  the integrals to note commute because of the singularity).

Comment: @bills Are there branches even for surface integral, btw? Does _Mathematica_ always uses Stokes theorem to solve a contour integral?

Comment: as another approach you can separately integrate over x>0 and x<0. Both converge, and add to 2.1733 ( `(4/3)*Sqrt[10]*(4 - Sqrt[10*Sqrt[2] - 2])`)

Comment: If you integrate in reverse order `I*NIntegrate[
  y*(1/(x - I*y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I*y)^(5/2)), {y, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}] ` the result `(*2.1733*)` is as expected from NIntegrate...

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Do you understand, why?

Comment: @george2079 Do you understand, why?

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch: Sorry, no idea!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Did you mean `I*Integrate[y*(1/(x - I*y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I*y)^(5/2)), {y, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]` or `NIntegrate`? I get the right answer with `Integrate` in the reverse order.

Comment: @Michael E2: Sorry, cut &paste error, I meant `Integrate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to stay above y=0 by adding infinitesimally small positive value `eps` to lower integration limit for `y` and then take limit:

`Limit[I*Integrate[y*(1/(x - I*y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I*y)^(5/2)), {x, -10, 10}, {y, eps, 10}, Assumptions -> eps > 0], eps -> 0] // FullSimplify`

`(*  (-4*Sqrt[10]*(-4 + Sqrt[-2 + 10*Sqrt[2]]))/3  *)`

Answer (score 4):

Integrate is wrong. Do ComplexExpand to get the right integral.

```
ceRe = FullSimplify[
   ComplexExpand[Re[I*y*(1/(x - I y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I y)^(5/2))], 
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], y >= 0 && x \[Element] Reals]

NIntegrate[ceRe, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
  MaxRecursion -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
  Exclusions -> {{0, 0}}]

(*   2.17329834703426526174107911927816608629584584526685923085449633834343\
       9718373530841484083310764572423   *)

cetr = TrigToExp[ceRe]

(*   (I y)/(2 ((x - I y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^(5/2) (x^2 + y^2)^(5/4)) - (
     I y ((x - I y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^(5/2))/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^(5/4)) - (
     I y)/(2 ((x + I y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^(5/2) (x^2 + y^2)^(5/4)) + (
     I y ((x + I y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^(5/2))/(2 (x^2 + y^2)^(5/4))   *)


Integrate[cetr, {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
   (N[#1, 20] &)[%]

(*   (11/606 + (3 I)/
 202) ((112 + 92 I) Sqrt[-10 + 10 I] + (22 - 18 I) Sqrt[-5 - 
 5 I] - (112 + 128 I) Sqrt[1 - 10 I] - (66 - 54 I) Sqrt[
 5 - 5 I] + (176 - 144 I) Sqrt[10] + (38 + 24 I) Sqrt[
 10 - 10 I] + (10 - 100 I) Sqrt[10 + 10 I] - (40 + 4 I) Sqrt[
 170 - 70 I] + 
 16 Sqrt[1105 + 262 I] - (44 - 36 I) Sqrt[
 5] \[Pi] - (40 + 4 I) Sqrt[10]
 ArcCoth[2 Sqrt[50/101 - (5 I)/101]] + (6 - 60 I) Sqrt[10]
 ArcCoth[Sqrt[1 + I]] - (88 - 72 I) Sqrt[5]
 ArcCoth[Sqrt[2]] - (6 - 60 I) Sqrt[10]
 ArcCoth[2/Sqrt[2 - I/5]] + (40 + 4 I) Sqrt[10]
 ArcCoth[(11/101 + (9 I)/101) Sqrt[10 - 100 I]] + (16 - 
  160 I) Sqrt[5] ArcTan[(1 + I)/Sqrt[2]] + (16 - 160 I) Sqrt[5]
 ArcTanh[(1 + I)/Sqrt[2]] + (2 - 20 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[1 - 1/2 (-1 + I)^(3/2)] + (18 + 22 I) (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[5]
 Log[1 + 1/2 (-1 + I)^(3/2)] + (2 - 20 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[1 - 1/Sqrt[1 + I]] - (2 - 20 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[1 + I]] - (3 - 30 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[((1 + 2 I) + 2 Sqrt[-1 + I]) (3 - 2 Sqrt[2])] + (3 - 
  30 I) Sqrt[10] Log[2 - Sqrt[2]] - (3 - 30 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[2 + Sqrt[2]] + (1 - 10 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[-Sqrt[1 - I] + Sqrt[2]] - (1 - 10 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[Sqrt[1 - I] + Sqrt[2]] - (10 + I) Sqrt[-5 - 5 I] Sqrt[1 - I]
 Log[-Sqrt[1 + I] + Sqrt[2]] + (10 + I) Sqrt[-5 - 5 I] Sqrt[1 - I]
 Log[Sqrt[1 + I] + Sqrt[2]] - (3 - 30 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[(-(1/2) + I/2) Sqrt[1 + 10 I] + Sqrt[10]] + (3 - 30 I) Sqrt[
10] Log[(1/2 - I/2) Sqrt[1 + 10 I] + Sqrt[10]] - (1 - 10 I) Sqrt[
10] Log[2 Sqrt[5] - Sqrt[10 - I]] + (1 - I) Sqrt[100 - 495 I]
 Log[2 Sqrt[5] - Sqrt[10 - I]] + (1 - 10 I) Sqrt[10]
 Log[2 Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[10 - I]] - (1 - I) Sqrt[100 - 495 I]
 Log[2 Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[10 - I]])   *)
```

FullSimplify[%]  gives

```
(*    8/3 (2 Sqrt[10] - Sqrt[-5 + 25 Sqrt[2]])    *)

(*  2.1732996388253877021 + 0.*10^-20 I  *)
```

Imaginary Part gives zero.

Comment: Trying to verify your code the last Integrate evaluates to `-14.6922`???(MMA 11.0.1 Windows64)

Comment: To @Ulrich Neumann.  I am working with MMA Version 8.0. Look at the full output of Integrate I added.

Comment: The result of Integrate (MMA 11.0.1) is significant  shorter(and obviosly wrong): `(* -(8/3) Sqrt[-5 + 25 Sqrt[2]]*)`

Comment: FullSimplified it is also much shorter  `8/3 (2 Sqrt[10] - Sqrt[-5 + 25 Sqrt[2]])` .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Same value as in my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

If you reverse the order of integration, you get the correct result:

```
I*Integrate[y*(1/(x - I*y)^(5/2) - 1/(x + I*y)^(5/2)), {y, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]
N[%]
(*
8/3 Sqrt[5 (7 + 5 Sqrt[2] - 4 Sqrt[-2 + 10 Sqrt[2]])]
2.1733
*)
```

The difference probably has to do with the handling of the singularity at `{0, 0}`, such as described in [What exactly does GenerateConditions do?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/what-exactly-does-generateconditions-do)

The difficulty is probably also connected with the branch cut for `Power`.

Comment: What allows you to reverse the order of integration? See for instance with `Integrate[(x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2, {x, 1, Infinity}, {y, 1, 
  Infinity}]` (taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)#Basic_theorems)).

Comment: @anderstood The region is compact and outside a (half) disk of radius $\epsilon$ at the origin the function is bounded; and the integral over the half disk is $16 \sqrt{\epsilon}\,/\,21$, and so vanishes as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Hence, with the aid of Fubini's theorem, one can show the order does not matter. (In polar coordinates, the integrand is rather easy to understand.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.